# I keep getting "TNS - no listener" error and can't connect in database

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I keep getting the no listener error and cannot connect to database.
Whenever I run localhost I get this:

```
Source Error
 a un handled exception was        generated during the execution of the    current web zequest. Internasion      regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified
using the exception stack trace below.
Stack trace:
[oracleException (0x80004005): ORA-125 41: TNS: No listener]
Oracle DataAccess.Client.oracleException. HandleError Helper (Int32 errcode, Oracleconnection conn, IntPtr opsErrctx, Oposgivalctx poposgivalctx
Oracle.DataAccess.client.oracleException. HandleError(Int32 errcode, Oracleconnection conn, IntPtr opsErrctx, object src) +41
Oracle.DataAccess.client.oracleconnection.Open +3288
JaxomLogin. Login +219
JaxiomLogin.Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) +26
system.Web.util.CalliHelper. EventArgFunctioncaller (IntPtr fp, Object o, object t, EventArgs e) +14
system.Web. Util.calli EventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(object sender, EventArgs e) +35
system.Web.UI. Control. OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
system.Web.UI. Control. LoadRecursive +50
system.Web.UI. Page. ProcessRequestMain(s001ean includestages beforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includestagesAfter AsyncPoint) +627
```

Listener.Ora file:

```
# Listener.ora Network Configuration File:
E: \app\Administrator product\11.1.0\db_2\network\admin listener.Qia
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION_LIST = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC) (KEY = EXTPROC1)) (ADDRESS =
(PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = SERVER) (PORT = 1521) ) ) )
```

Tnsnames.ora file:

```
# Tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:
E: \app\Administrator\product\11.1.0\db_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = SERVER) (PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
)
```

What I tried in order to solve the error ana didn’t work:

1-changing HOST in listener.Ora to 0.0.0.0 and to computer’s name
2-removing spaces in tnsnames.Ora
3-Turning firewall off
4-Usung service name instead of SID
5-Restarting lcnrctl from command prompt
6-Restarting Oracle services

I also can’t find the service named Oracle listener in the services.

When I type lcnrctl status in command prompt I get this:
[image]

What is wrong and how to solve the problem and connect normally to the database?

Comment: 1. Make sure the database is running. Start the service and observe what the database alert-log file is saying: Please translate to Windows: # display the alert log
alog () {
  less ${ORACLE_BASE}/diag/rdbms/$(echo ${ORACLE_SID} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')*/${ORACLE_SID}/trace/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log
}
The database will register to the listener once the db-instance is running. (But this doesn't necessarily mean the database is open...)

Comment: @Bjarte Brandt where can I find the database alert log file?

Comment: I have a bash-function "alog" for quickly reading the alert log. It is written for Linux, you need to translate this into Windows  "${ORACLE_BASE}/diag/rdbms/$(echo ${ORACLE_SID} | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')*/${ORACLE_SID}/trace/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log". You will find ORACLE_BASE and ORACLE_SID in the Windows Registry. You can also just search your HD for "alert_<ORACLE_SID>.log"

Comment: Ok but where to write it? In command prompt or where?

Comment: I think you should go with the Search function in Windows Explorer. Search for "alert_<ORACLE_SID>.log" . If you are planning to administer an Oracle database, you will need to master the command line. In Windows you can use cmd.exe, Powershell or WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). At the same time you are running a very old version of the database and most likely an old version of the OS..Windows Server 2003? Hard to say where you should start. Learn the command-line. Search github.com for code, scripts and snippets. Best of luck!

Comment: @BjarteBrandt - the reported error (ORA-125 41: TNS: No listener)  has zero to do with whether or not the database is running.   This error means one thing and one thing only - there was not a listener running at the IP address and port that was specified by the client request.  While the output of lsnrctl indicates that it does not know of any databases (and so - probably - the database is not open), that is not the cause of the reported error.

Comment: Your error stack indicates some sort of java-based client.  Let's cut that out for the moment.  Please update your question to show the result of 'tnsping orcl' (where 'orcl' is the entry from your tnsnames.ora)

Comment: @EdStevens You are correct. "TNS: No listener" involves the listener only. I went straight to the listener output and lack of services exposed. Thanks.